# Do offline enabled chrome apps auto-update?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode

I have an [offline enabled](https://github.com/lookitscook/kiosk/blob/master/manifest.json#L15) [chrome application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban?hl=en). When developing the application I am able to publish it, restart the device twice (once to get the update, once to apply it) and see the latest version. However, [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled) (under "How they behave") indicates offline enabled apps should not auto update. Google Cloud Support has also confirmed auto updates should be disabled to one of my customers. Why am I able to see the app auto update?

Comment: All the documentation says is that offline-enabled apps won't be checked for an update when started. It doesn't say the update will never be performed on a schedule. The phrasing is just awkward.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, until a customer reported their devices were not receiving app updates and were told by Google Cloud Support: "Based on this article: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled, 'Each time a Kiosk App launches, the system checks for updates in the Chrome Web Store to ensure that the latest app version is installed, unless the app is set to be enabled offline' I was checking the manifest file for this App (Kiosk afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban) and indeed, it has been configured as Offline, this means that it will not auto-update."

Comment: Uhm your comment seems to be repeating the question. See the next line in the documentation which is what I was referring to: "Thereafter, the system checks for updates every five hours and installs the update if available. If the device is offline, the update is rescheduled to a later time when the app is back online."

Comment: True, I simply wanted to include the exact response I was referring to in the original question. I'm asking since the functionality I'm seeing is not what is described in the documentation.

Comment: Er, you observe an update and the documentation doesn't contradict it AFAICT. The support team may be easily mistaking.

Comment: Correct. I would leave it at that, except I have a customer who's devices are NOT updating (consistent with the support comment but not my experience). I was directed to ask here by Google Web Store Developer Support since they were unable to  clarify how this works.